# determinant method vs cross-product area of a triangle

Tags: algorithm

I was wondering which method(determinant method or cross-product) is more efficient to calculate the area of a triangle?
With determinants i thought at area=1/2*det() For this method i use this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleArea.html .
With cross-product i thought at area=det( )but with cross product. When they do not have origin in 0(0,0) i have to translate the system which means to substract from every point the coordonates of the origin.
That is what i do.

Comment: I think they're exactly the same. Please elaborate on the two methods, then we can count the number of arithmetic operations. There may be potential for speedup in the determinant case if you use Gaussian elimination, but the speedup may not be so great for 3x3 matrices.

Comment: Here is good description: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleArea.html just count required operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by "**determinant method**" (couldn't find that in Google) you mean the following:

Given 3 points `A`, `B`, `C` (assume they're [position vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_(vector))) let `a = B-C`, `b = A-C`. Then because of [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant)'s special property:

> the absolute value of the determinant of real vectors is equal to the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by those vectors

we have `|det(M)| = 2 SABC` where `SABC` is area of triangle `ABC` and `M` is a special matrix that "defines" that "parallelepiped":

[image]

So area of the triangle can be calculated as `SABC = 1/2 |axby - aybx|` where `ax = Bx - Cx` and others defined in a similar way.

This formula is quite straightforward and efficient. The only problem with it is that it only works for points of a plane (2D case). If you have your points somewhere in n-dimensional space you need to draw a plane through them first.

In 3D case, you can make use of cross-product formula. It can be seen as an extension of the aforementioned approach, I'll elaborate on that later.

**Cross-product** method works as follows: take `a` and `b` as before and note that length of their cross-product equals to area of corresponding parallelogram:

[image]

Let `v = a × b`. Then `SABC = 1/2 sqrt(vx2 + vy2 + vz2)`. Note that you don't need to explicitly compute `v`: each of its components can be expressed as 2D determinant which has simple closed form.

If you have 2D vectors you can easily embed them in 3D space by adding constant 3rd component (0, for example). Turns out, in that case `vx` and `vy` will zero out leaving us with S<sub>ABC</sub> = 1/2 |v<sub>z</sub>| which will coincide with the determinant method's answer.

---

So, in conclusion

- Use determinant method if your points in 2D space.
- Use cross-product method if your points in 3D space (you can use it
  in 2D case too, but some subexpressions will always evaluate to 0).
- In case of n-dimensional space neither method work.